# Setting up a session counter for a time difference

Tags: r

I have a table which captures the interaction of users of a website. Column 'id' is the unique identifier of a user. 'time' is the time difference of the present interaction with the last one. 'conv' represents the step where the user converted or not(1,0). The user might convert several times or not convert at all. I need to tag a session counter whose logic is as follows:

1. when the id is same and the diff is less than 10 the counter shall give the preceding counter value.
2. when the id is same and the diff is greater than 10 the counter shall be incremented by +1.
3. when the id changes the counter should reset to 1. Also after the user has converted(i.e. conv =1) and the 'time' is greater than 10 then the counter should reset to one.
   The dummy dataframe would look like this :

   ```
   df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),  conv = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0), time= c(0,3,15,18,9,5,17,7,15,5,5,45,40,5))

   id |conv |time    
   ----  
   1 | 0 | 0    
   1 | 0 | 3    
   1 | 0 | 15       
   1 | 0 | 18    
   1 | 1 | 9     
   1 | 0 | 5    
   1 | 0 | 17    
   1 | 0 | 7     
   1 | 0 | 15    
   1 | 1 | 5    
   1 | 0 | 5    
   2 | 0 | 0     
   2 | 0 | 40    
   2 | 0 | 5
   ```

   Final Table should be like this :

   ```
   id |conv |time | counter   
   ----  
   1 | 0 | 0 | 1  
   1 | 0 | 3 | 1  
   1 | 0 | 15 | 2     
   1 | 0 | 18 | 3  
   1 | 1 | 9 | 3   
   1 | 0 | 5 | 3  
   1 | 0 | 17 | 1  
   1 | 0 | 7 | 1  
   1 | 0 | 15 | 2  
   1 | 1 | 5 | 2  
   1 | 0 | 5 | 2  
   2 | 0 | 0 | 1   
   2 | 0 | 40 | 2  
   2 | 0 | 5 | 2
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to loop through the rows. Here is an example (not sure if it gives you the exact results you want, the example was a bit confusing, but you can use the same approach):

```
df <- data.frame(id= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                 conv=  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),  
                 time= c(0, 3, 15, 18, 9, 5, 17, 7, 15, 5, 5, 45, 40, 5),
                 counter= numeric(0))



for (i in c(2:nrow(df))){  # For each row in the data frame (starting at row #2):

    if (df[i, "id"] == df[i - 1, "id"]){  # If current row's ID equals previous rows ID..

        # definitions for clarity
        time <- df[i, "time"]
        prev_time <- df[i - 1, "time"] 

        if (abs(time - prev_time) < 10){  # if absolute diff less than 10
            df[i, "counter"] <- df[i - 1, "counter"]  # current time = previous time
        } else {
            df[i, "counter"] <- df[i, "counter"] + 1  # current time incremented by 1
        }  

        # check conv
        if (df[i, "conv"] == 1 & df[i, "time"] > 10){
            df[i, "counter"] <- 1
        }


    } else {  # If the ID numbers don't match

        df[i, "counter"] <- 1  # set counter to 1

    }
}
```